# Is mongorestore ditrectly to a path with the --dbpath faster than restoring to a running mongod instance?

Tags: backup, database, mongodb, backup-restoration

What and how much is it faster:

`#mongod not running`

`mongorestore --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb  --db test /some_dump`

or

`#mongod running`

`mongorestore --db test /some_dump`

?

I could not quickly find an answer on the web and have no time now to do a benchmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now at least, they are basically equivalent, assuming the `mongod` is not doing anything else significant.  To explain, in versions 2.6 and below, the `mongorestore` utility effectively contains the `mongod` binary which allows it to act as a `mongod` and insert to data files without a `mongod` running already.  The advantage a solo `mongorestore` usually has is that it won't be doing anything else whereas usually a running `mongod` will be replicating or servicing other operations besides the `mongorestore`.

From version 2.8 onward, this will no longer be the case (unless something changes, 2.8 is not yet released as of writing this), and you will be required to have a `mongod` running in order to perform a `mongorestore` (or a `mongodump` for that matter). Therefore, with an eye on the future, running a `mongod` and using that to perform the restore would be the advisable method to use.